# Select2: loading selected values

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Im trying to load the *selected* values from the database into my multiple select box.

When I load the option initially from the database, It work perfect.

[image]

But I would like to add the **SELECTED** items for this rrecord.
I've tried a few approaches which is a bit hacky, like this.

```
                var keywordArray = new Array();
                keywordArray = test[0].keyword.split(",");

                for( var x = 0; x < keywordArray.length ; x++){
                    foundKeyword = $( "select" ).find("option[value="+keywordArray[x]+"]").text();
                    $('.select2-choices').prepend("<li class='select2-search-choice'><div>" + foundKeyword + "</div><a href='#' class='select2-search-choice-close' tabindex='-1'></a></li>");
                    $('.select2-search-field input').attr("aria-activedescendant","select2-result-label-25");
                    $('.select2-search-field input').css("width", "10px");
                    $('.select2-search-field input').removeClass("select2-default");


                }
```

This CANT be how its done, and besides it does not work propperly

[image]

even though the SELECTED keywords appear to be there. You cant delete them and the associated value in the dropdown is still selectable (not greyed out).

Ive tried a example from the net as-well, Which did not work

```
                var pills = [{id:0, text: "ECHO"}, {id:1, text: "BRAVO"}];

                $('#media_keywords').select2({
                    placeholder: "Select a pill",
                    data: function() { return {results: pills}; }
                });
```

So my question is, how do you load the SELECTED data from the DB and refresh or re-initialise the `select2` selected area? This also needs to disable the select capability of items already selected.

Comment: whether the the select2 element is a `select` or an `input`

Comment: Okay, Ive tried what you put in the other question and it worked.
`$('#media_keywords').select2().select2('val', keywordArray)`
Thanks Arun

Comment: My `Select2` was derived from a `select` yes

Comment: @ArunPJohny I know its quite a old post but could you please provide more details as i am also facing the same issue. i am fetching the data from database and it is coming in keywordArray but for some reason it is not showing in select2. By the way i am using input. (Select2 version is 3.5.4)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So after a little help from `Mr Arun P Johny`,
I finaly got to the **very simple** answer.

Maybe I dont fully grasp it yet, but is I understand correctly, you have to approach the loading differently depending if you are creating your `Select2` from a `input` or a `select`.

Mine was created from a select so getting the data back from the AJAX call, I simply used the array containing the ID values of the selected items and passed it through like this

```
 $('#media_keywords').select2().select2('val', keywordArray)
```

`keywordArray` being the array of IDs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know its quite a old post but could you please provide more details as i am also facing the same issue. i am fetching the data from database and it is coming in keywordArray but for some reason it is not showing in select2. By the way i am using input. (Select2 version is 3.5.4)

Comment: @CalculatingMachine I will see what I can do, bit long ago and not using this anymore.

Comment: ahh. I am still trying but not able to figure it out. bit sad but thanks for your reply.

Comment: Thanks! It helped, but I had to delete the first `.select2()` so, as example, I ended up using:
`$('#media_keywords').select2('val', keywordArray);`

Answer (score 0):

by jQuery in Multiple mode:

```
var selectedValues = ["1", "2"];
$('.my_select').val(selectedValues).trigger('change');
```