# Select2: Showing multiple selected values

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-selectors

Similar to this FIDDLE, how would you get is to show more than one selected value on load?

```
<select multiple>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>


$('select').select2().select2('val','3')
```

[image]

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AeXYN/)**

NEEDS to show something similar to this ON LOAD
[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make the select to be multiple then pass the values as an array

```js
$('select').select2().select2('val', ['3', '1'])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.3.0/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.3.0/select2.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple" style="width:300px">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/54j3v660/)

---

After 4.1

```js
$('select').select2().val(['3', '2']).trigger('change')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<select multiple="multiple" style="width:300px">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/54j3v660/7/)

Comment: Arun, may I refer you to one of my other question similar to this one PLEASE. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25639251/select2-loading-selected-values

Comment: @FaiZalDong select2 version used

Comment: @FaiZalDong if you are using a newer version of select2 http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/54j3v660/7/

Answer (score 1):

Try the below, it works for me.

```
var array =  ['3', '1'];
$('#your-select-id').val(array).trigger("change");
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to this answer